# Fatslane error Google Api Error: Invalid request - APK specifies a version code that has already been used

Tags: flutter, dart, fastlane

My latest build number (version code) is 58.

```yaml
# pubspec.yaml
version: 1.1.0+58
```

I am using Fastlane to build and upload to the play store. The build command I am using is

```bash
flutter run --flavor development --build-number=#{ENV['version_code']}
```

where `version_code` is automatically incremented before each build.

I can see during the build process version_code is incremented correctly to 59. The latest google play version code is 58.